# How can I organize the content of my controllers in Laravel if i have reports?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a Laravel app and I have controllers with the CRUD methods, but I need to show reports and I'm not sure if I have to create a controller called 'Reports' or I have to put each report function inside the controller:

1. First Option:

   - Controllers/ProductController.php

     - Functions (Create, Read, Edit, Update, Delete)
   - Controllers/CategoryController.php

     - Functions (Create, Read, Edit, Update, Delete)
   - Controllers/ReportController.php

     - Functions (TopProducts, TopCategories)
2. Second Option:

   - Controllers/ProductController.php

     - Functions (Create, Read, Edit, Update, Delete, TopProducts)
   - Controllers/CategoryController.php

     - Functions (Create, Read, Edit, Update, Delete, TopCategories)

I hope you can tell me a which is the best option or your own alternative.
Thanks.

Comment: any way is fine.

Comment: You may organize your controllers with naming as `Controllers/ProductReportController.php`, `Controllers/CategoryReportController.php` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I want to have a controller standard because our project has more than 50 tables and we're three developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do the first option because your code will be clearer and more separated.

This way, if you want to create more reports from different tables, you will have everything in one controller.

I would advise against option 1 if you are using queries that are already defined in the other controllers, following DRY principles.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, those are some examples because we need to work with more than 50 tables and we're three developers. Do you think that first option is the best option for our project? If you have another idea, I'll be grateful.

Comment: If you think you are going to create a lot of reports, then I recommend creating more controllers, having in mind that if you can reuse some queries for said reports, you should put them in the same controller. For example, if table1 and table2 share some queries, I recommend putting them in the same controller so you reuse code. Hope this helps!